# Renewal of etcd certificates

Tags: ssl

Recently faced with ETCD certificate renewal. I wanted to renew certificates for 100 years. I did everything according to the documentation, but not all certificates were renewed for 100 years. ca.pem is only renewable for 5 years `notAfter=Jun  9 09:19:00 2026 GMT`

[certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j40Di.png)
Can ca.pem be extended for a longer period?

My config

```
cat ca-config.json 
{
    "signing": {
        "default": {
            "expiry": "876000h"
        },
        "profiles": {
            "server": {
                "expiry": "876000h",
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "server auth",
                    "client auth"
                ]
            },
            "client": {
                "expiry": "876000h",
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "client auth"
                ]
            },
            "peer": {
                "expiry": "876000h",
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "server auth",
                    "client auth"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This required changing ca-csr.json

```
{
    "CA": {
        "expiry": "876000h",
        "pathlen": 0
    },
    "CN": "etcd",
    "key": {
        "algo": "rsa",
        "size": 2048
    }
}
```

And then regenerate the certificate

`cfssl gencert -initca ca-csr.json | cfssljson -bare ca -`

We see the result
`openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in ca.pem`

`notAfter=May 19 09:26:00 2121 GMT`